# Is there any shortcut to select entire code block in Atom similar to Option + Up Arrow in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, shortcut, atom-editor

Is there any shortcut to select entire code block in **Atom** similar to <kbd>Option + Up Arrow</kbd> in PhpStorm?

It helps you select the code block and if you press <kbd>Option + Up Arrow</kbd> again, it expands the selection to its parent block.

Is there any shortcut or plugin to have that feature? It makes it faster to work with heavy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now built into Atom.

https://blog.atom.io/2018/10/23/atom-1-32.html

Select Larger/Smaller Syntax Node

Answer (score 3):

Yes! You want the **[expand-region](https://github.com/aki77/atom-expand-region)** plugin, it's great! Add these to your `keymap.cson` to expand the region with option-up (alt-up on windows) :

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'alt-up': 'expand-region:expand'
  'alt-down': 'expand-region:shrink'
```

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl+Alt+M</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd+Ctrl+M</kbd> on Mac) selects entire code inside the current brackets. It doesn't expand to the parent block though.
If you need that feature, you might want to look for some package. There is [`select-scope`](https://atom.io/packages/select-scope) package that claims to add that functionality. I haven't tested if it works. It also doesn't seem to show up on the package list in every atom version.
If you decide to try that package out, you may need to override it's key-binding as it uses <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd>.